# What are the main differences betwen EOSIO multi_index and Boost multi_index?

Tags: multi-index, c++, persistence-api

Inspired by [this comment](https://eosio.stackexchange.com/questions/6/are-tables-dbs-stored-in-ram-and-held-by-multiple-block-producers/1394#comment5_6), I was wondering what are the main differences between `eosio::multi_index` and `boost:multi_index` and why do they exist?

[The documentation](https://developers.eos.io/eosio-cpp/docs) notes that there are important differences, but does not go into much detail about the differences:

> The Multi-Index container interface eosio::multi_index provides a
>   homogeneous container of an arbitrary C++ type (and it does not need
>   to be a plain-old data type or be fixed-size) that is kept sorted in
>   multiple indices by keys of various types that are derived from the
>   objects. It can be compared to a traditional database table with rows,
>   columns, and indices. It can also be easily compared to Boost
>   Multi-index Containers. In fact many of the member function signatures
>   of eosio::multi_index are modeled after boost::multi_index, although
>   there are important differences.

Comment: Jackson Kelley just released his Udemy course, and he uploaded some of his videos on YouTube.  He goes over the multi index and the similarities/differences with the boost multi index container. https://www.youtube.com/user/jackodwhacko/videos

Comment: The code for multi_index.hpp is in https://github.com/EOSIO/eosio.cdt/libraries/eosiolib
It does pull in boost/hana.hpp but cannot see where in the EOSIO implementation HANA is it being used?
Boost is getting used in action.hpp, dispatcher, datastream...